# Is it possible to intercept Notifications from Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, service-worker

I'm trying to create a Chrome Extension that listens to Desktop Notifications (Twitter for example) for a custom alert system but I'm stuck.

Currently I can intercept Desktop Notifications for the current tab by monkeypatching the Notification object but most of the messengers use Service Workers for their notifications. I tried monkeypatching the service worker register method but I can't find any way to load custom code. Loading the service worker from chrome-extension:// or anything else then the domain fails. This doesn't seem possible or am I missing something?